# Ionic2 ion-input not working on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, simulator

I submitted my first ionic application for review to the App Store.

Basically, **Apple rejected the review because they couldn’t login to my application. They said that when they tap on the username textfield, the keyboard doesn’t show up** (They provided a screenshot and I have noted that they are using a simulator for testing).

I have being researching that there is a bug on the iOS Simulator, *and the way to fix the problem is to Toggle the Software Keyboard, or uncheck the "Connect Hardware Keyboard"*.

I have a lot of back and forth messages with Apple, trying to explain this, but they replied that it still not working.

Honestly, I am not sure they followed the Keyboard steps. As far as I know, it works as expected on phisical devices, and in iOS Simulator when you toggle the keyboard.

Is there any solution, or another way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the shown keyboard in Simulator?

Comment: I agree - I have exactly the same issue. I'm surprised they are testing on a simulator to be fair. They tend to test on hardware. Cmd+K is the key combination to fix this - what are they saying?

Comment: I have already provided screenshots and videos showing that the keyboard is showing properly. I insisted that they need to toggle the Software Keyboard, disconnect the Hardware Keyboard. They keep saying that I need to fix the problem, but I'm not sure they tried to re-test the application with the solution I have provided.

Answer (score 5):

This is a well known bug that can be circumvented in two ways.

1. Press **CMD + K** and then click into the field.
2. **Disable** "**Slow Animations**" which can be found under "Debug" -> "Slow Animations". For me, that permanently fixes the issue. Shortcut is: CMD + T

**Regarding Apple's rejection:**
Tell Apple, that this is a known Bug ONLY for the simulator, and that they should disable slow animations and press CMD + K (twice).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apparently, I requested a phone call to Apple. They were using an external keyboard connected to an iPad. But when they tested without the external keyboard, it worked just fine. They approved my application.

Comment: Nice to know. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use one of these events on the text inpu:

keyup, keydown, keypress, input

and then use this plugin and explicitly show/hide the keyboard?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

Comment: As far as I know, the keyboard is being showed, but the iOS Simulator gets stuck when detect that there is another Keyboard (the hardware keyboard). Anyways, it is worth to try.

Comment: In your question, you say " the keyboard doesn’t show up"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line to config.xml:

`<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />`

so that the keyboard will show in iOS when a text input is tapped.
(Note that Android does not require this additional config.)

You may also need to focus into the field with JavaScript directly; declare an ElementRef:

`@ViewChild('elemName') yourField: ElementRef;`

and then focus into its native element element:

`this.yourField.nativeElement.focus();`